# Add Class to First / Last Elements Dynamically Generated by Each Loops

Tags: jquery, html, addclass, each, css-selectors

This does seem like a pretty dopey question even with my limited coding experience, but I'm damned if I can find the solution on my own, or here. I have multiple elements on my HTML page with a class of `.innertables`. I am, based on a separate variable, wrapping this class in dynamically generated HTML like so:

```
var limit = 3 //dynamically generated, could be any integer
$( ".innertables" ).each(function() {
    var divs = $(this).children('.togcont').slice(0,limit); 
        for(var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            divs.wrapAll("<div class='wrap'><div class='pre'></div><div class='morecont'>More -&gt;</div><div class='lesscont'>&lt;- Back</div> </div>");
        }
    });
```

This generates multiple instances of this example HTML snippet:

```
<div class="innertables">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="pre">Header Text
            <div class="togcont">Text 1</div>
            <div class="togcont">Text 2</div>
            <div class="togcont">Text 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="morecont">More -&gt;</div>
        <div class="lesscont">&lt;- Back</div>
    </div>
   <div class="wrap">
        <div class="pre">Header Text
            <div class="togcont">Text 4</div>
            <div class="togcont">Text 5</div>
            <div class="togcont">Text 6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="morecont">More -&gt;</div>
        <div class="lesscont">&lt;- Back</div>
    </div>
   <div class="wrap">
        <div class="pre">Header Text
            <div class="togcont">Text 7</div>
            <div class="togcont">Text 8</div>
            <div class="togcont">Text 9</div>
        </div>
        <div class="morecont">More -&gt;</div>
        <div class="lesscont">&lt;- Back</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far, so good. What I want to do is add second classes to the very first instance of `morecont` and the last instances of `morecont` and `lesscont` in each instance of `.innertables`. It seems like adding the following to the each loop of `.innertables` would do the trick:

```
$( ".morecont" ).first().addClass( "shiftleft" ); 
$( ".lesscont" ).last().addClass( "hide" );
$( ".morecont" ).last().addClass( "hide" );
```

But this adds classes to the very first `.morecont` in ALL of the `.innertables` on the page, and the last instances in all of them, as well. I tried different things like adding `.wrap` as the first class, e.g. `$( ".wrap .morecont" ).first()`, with the same result, and something like `$( ".wrap .morecont:first-child" ).addClass( "shiftleft" );` with no result at all. I understood an .each() loop would traverse every instance of `.innertables` and be able to makes changes to every one being looped. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using jQuery's each function.

```
$(".innertables").each(function() {
   $(this).find(".morecont").first().addClass( "shiftleft" );
   $(this).find(".lesscont").last().addClass( "hide" );
   $(this).find(".morecont").last().addClass( "hide" );
});
```

This basically tells jQuery to find the first/last of what you want *within* the scope of each `.innertable`.

What you're doing wrong is that you're using an `.each()` loop but you're not narrowing the selected elements down using `$(this).children( "selector" )`. It wouldn't work if you directly used `$( "selector" )` even if it's inside `.each()`.

**edit: changed `.children()` to `.find()`**

Comment: you might be able to use :first and :last jquery selectors in order to do this without a loop?

Comment: That makes sense but sorry to say, that is not working -- no additional classes are being added, not even when I put `$(this).children(".morecont").addClass( "shiftleft" );` in an `$(".innertables").each()` loop. Now, if I add something like `$( ".morecont" ).addClass( "shiftleft" );`, every `.morecont`  element gets an additional `.shiftleft` class, but of course that's not what I want. But the solution must be in that `$.each()`, I have to imagine.

Comment: @jimiayler Whoops. I had a closer look at your code, and that's because we're supposed to use `$(this).find()` instead of `$(this).children()` because `children()` only looks at the direct children of the element. 

I have edited my original answer, see the new code in that.

Comment: Good "find"! :} Works like a charm now. Thanks very much for your help.